# file upload fail using HTTP POST through C++

Tags: java, c++, web-services, httpwebrequest, http-headers

I am getting HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error what i am trying to do is i am sending a http packet though socket the http packet contains data and a file here is my packet

```
POST /my/service HTTP/1.0
Host: myhostname.com
Accept: */*   
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----acbn1234
Content-Length: 62

------acbn1234
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="segment"

name
------acbn1234
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="segid"

abc123
------acbn1234
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="segname"

segment1
------acbn1234
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="txtfile"; filename="textfile.txt"
Content-Type: text/plain

segment information this the data in the file
------acbn1234--
```

the server side is apache tomcat server shows exception on console

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet ssp-dispatcher threw exception
org.apache.commons.fileupload.MultipartStream$MalformedStreamException: Stream ended unexpectedly
    at org.apache.commons.fileupload.MultipartStream.readHeaders(MultipartStream.java:538)
    at org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase$FileItemIteratorImpl.findNextItem(FileUploadBase.java:999)
    at org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase$FileItemIteratorImpl.hasNext(FileUploadBase.java:1063)
    at org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase.parseRequest(FileUploadBase.java:357)
    at org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload.parseRequest(ServletFileUpload.java:126)
    at org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver.parseRequest(CommonsMultipartResolver.java:155)
    at org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver.resolveMultipart(CommonsMultipartResolver.java:138)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.checkMultipart(DispatcherServlet.java:887)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:750)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:669)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:585)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:291)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProcessor.process(Http11AprProcessor.java:877)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11AprProtocol.java:594)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$Worker.run(AprEndpoint.java:1675)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

where i am wrong my HTTP packet is ok the server doesn't shows bad request i.e 404 i think it shows internal server error 500. ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your content-length header is incorrect. Your data is about 400 bytes, not 62.

Comment: hi sjoerd is it the only mistake ??? what about the stack trace shown by the server stream ended unexpectedly ?

Comment: The HTTP reader only reads 62 bytes from the stream. Then the multipart reader complains that it is too short: it ended before it expected to.